# How to display text from EditText to ListView?

Tags: android

I want to display in the listview what I have type in the EditText, so everytime I'm going to input something in the EditText, it will automatically add in the array adn display it using a listview. 
Need a help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked using a ListAdapter? If not, doesnt matter. Here's how it could be done (untested and written by the fly)

```
public class ListViewExampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_listviewexampleactivity);

  final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
  final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
  final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
  final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


   final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
   listview.setAdapter(adapter);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      if (edt.getText().toString() != null) {
       adapter.addItem(edt.getText().toString());
   } 
 });    
}

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    List<String> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.data = (ArrayList)objects;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  String item = getItem(position);
  return mIdMap.get(item);
}
public void addItem(String item) {
  data.add(item);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: What if the array is still empty? And it will get string from what i have entered in the edittext?

Comment: Adapter also supports Lists, not only arrays. Using empty list should work. After adding a value to the list, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: modified. now you have null entries and it will be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ArrayAdapter` to handle the list of `String` you want to display.

On the `Button` click, you can then add the `EditText` content to the adapter and then `notifyDataSetChanged()` the adapter so it "redraws" itself and finally clear the `EditText` content.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText input;
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // android:id="@+id/input"
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        // android:id="@+id/list"
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // android:onClick="addToList"
    public void addToList(View view) {
        adapter.add(input.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Clear the input
        input.setText("");
    }
}
```

With a layout similar to:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add to list"
        android:onClick="addToList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One last thing, can I add any elements like images and other text in the listview that can't be modified when the user enter the text? I mean everytime the user enter a text, it will also display the image or the text.

Comment: You can, but you will have to create your own adapter to customize the layout used for each "line" and fill these lines with the right data. Check this sample : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown

Comment: Do not forget to validate an answer so others know your problem is solved. Mine or @Emanuel Seibold's, as I see it, it's a working solution too.